# Restrict typesense to localhost only

Tags: typesense

I am trying to host `typesense` in a self-hosted virtual machine. I don't want to expose the `typesense` to the public. I want to restrict access from `localhost`
only. How can I restrict the `typesense` from accessing outside?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `--api-address` and `--peering-address` to `127.0.0.1` to ensure that Typesense is only listening for inbound connections from localhost.

These two parameters are documented here: https://typesense.org/docs/0.23.1/api/server-configuration.html#using-command-line-arguments

> `--api-address`
>
> Address to which Typesense API service binds. Default: `0.0.0.0`

> `--peering-address`
>
> Internal IP address to which Typesense peering service binds. If this parameter is not specified, Typesense will attempt to use the first available internal IP.

Comment: can you please explain what is --peering-address? What is the difference between --pering-address and --api-address?

Comment: `--api-address` is where you make all the API calls to Typesense. `--pering-address` is used by Typesense internally when you setup a [highly available cluster](https://typesense.org/docs/guide/high-availability.html) to sync replication status between the nodes.